# How to convert a string to HTMLElement using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, type-conversion

I wonder how to convert a string to an HTMLElement ?

I have tryed :

```
$('<i data-icon="'+icon+'" class="smiley-big"></i>')
```

But in console it shows type: [object Object]
If I log existing ellements in the Dom like this:

```
$('[class^="smiley"]').each(function(){
     console.log(this);
});
```

I get [object HTMLElement]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547159/deriving-an-htmlelement-object-from-jquery-object

Comment: you are answering ur own question...you want html element and you are getting object of html element..use that object wherever u want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('<i data-icon="'+icon+'" class="smiley-big"></i>').get(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because a jQuery object is an array-like object which contains all the selected elements. In this case, it contains only one element, and that is the one you just created. Thus, we can access it via index 0:

```
var newI = $('<i data-icon="'+icon+'" class="smiley-big"></i>')[0];
```

In the case of `each`, it iterates over the object and returns each item as `this` in the function, which in your case, is your newly created HTML element.